# How to add custom field in Customer Registration on Magento 2.2?

Tags: php, magento, registration, custom-fields, magento2.2

1. I want to add Custom field in Customer Registration on Magento 2.2
2. I 've tried following code but it's not working.
3. I tried InstallData.php

   ```
     use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
     use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
     use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
     use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

     class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
     {
         protected $customerSetupFactory;

         private $attributeSetFactory;

         public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
         {
             $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
             $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
         }

         public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
         {

             $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

             $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
             $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

             $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
             $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
             $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'intrestedin', [
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'label' => 'Custom Field',
                 'input' => 'text',
                 'required' => true,
                 'visible' => true,
                 'user_defined' => true,
                 'sort_order' => 1000,
                 'position' => 1000,
                 'system' => 0,
             ]);
             $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
                 ->addData([
                     'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                     'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                     'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
                 ]);

             $attribute->save();
         }
     }
   ```

Comment: tried upgrade and di:compile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to create a module and add customer attribute. you can create module from here- https://mage2gen.com/

After installing the module , you can run setup upgrade and deploy command.

Comment: Awesome tools. Thank you so much.